# Go-gorm returns all records if filtered with Struct instance that has default Value in a field

Tags: go, go-gorm

Lets say we have the following struct:

```
type Task struct {
    ...
    Completed bool      `gorm:"default:false"                  json:"-"`
}
```

There are 5 entries in the MySQL DB:

- 2 of them have `Completed=1`
- 3 of them have `Completed=0`

I face the following peculiarity:

```
db, err = gorm.Open("mysql", connstr)
var ret []Task

// This returns 3 rows
db.Debug().Model(&Task{}).Find(&ret, "Completed =?", false)
// This returns 2 rows
db.Debug().Model(&Task{}).Find(&ret, Task{Completed: true})
// BUT THIS RETURNS 5 ROWS!
db.Debug().Model(&Task{}).Find(&ret, Task{Completed: false})
```

Any ideas why is this happening? The SQL executed at the last call was:
`SELECT * FROM 'tasks'`

I would like to avoid writing a new SQL query for each struct field. Passing the struct (object) seems more sensible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Reason

GORM looks at the fields of the struct provided to `Find()`, and checks to see which fields are set, to construct the query. So in the 2nd example, it sees that `Completed` is set to `true`, and adds a WHERE clause to the query:

```golang
db.Debug().Model(&Task{}).Find(&ret, Task{Completed: true})
```

generates:

```sql
SELECT * FROM "tasks" WHERE "tasks"."completed" = true
```

In the second example, GORM has no way of knowing if you passed in `Task{Completed: false}` or simply `Task{}` because `false` is the [zero-value](https://tour.golang.org/basics/12) of a `bool`.

The same thing would happen if you had a field that was an `int` and tried to query for `0`:

```golang
db.Debug().Model(&Task{}).Find(&ret, Task{Num: 0}) // Generates: SELECT * FROM 'tasks'
```

#### Solution

If you really want to use the struct for queries, you can change your model so that `Completed` is a `*bool` instead of a `bool`. Since the **zero-value** of a pointer is nil, providing a pointer to false will tell GORM to add that clause:

```golang
trueBool := true
falseBool := false

db.Debug().Model(&Task{}).Find(&ret, Task{Completed: &falseBool})
db.Debug().Model(&Task{}).Find(&ret, Task{Completed: &trueBool})
```

generate (respectively)

```sql
SELECT * FROM "tasks" WHERE "tasks"."completed" = false
SELECT * FROM "tasks" WHERE "tasks"."completed" = true
```

Just remember that doing this means that `Completed` can be saved in the DB as `NULL` if not set.